# The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'ins'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again., SQL state S0022 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\cit\con2.php on line 8

```
<?php 
$test='C:\xampp\htdocs\cit\con1.mdb';
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$test", "", "");
$txtroll=$_REQUEST['txtroll'];
$sql= "insert into inst(ID,ins) values (NULL,'$txtroll')";
$rs =   odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the field ins is correct, also should there be a space after the table name?

Comment: Are you sure Column/Field `ins` exists in the DB table?

Comment: yes sir the field 'ins' exists in the db table

Comment: I see that you have a later question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21578059/2144390) which seems to relate to the same table. If this question is no longer an outstanding issue then please consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my WAMP test box and I could recreate your issue. Your code inserted the new record without error.