# resource(3) of type (odbc result) while i am inserting data to ms access using php script

Tags: php, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

my code is-

```
<?php
$test='C:\xampp\htdocs\cit\con1.mdb';
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$test", "", "");
$txtroll=$_REQUEST['txtroll'];
$all="face";
$sql="INSERT INTO inst (info,sname) VALUES ('$all','$txtroll')";
$rs =   odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
var_dump($rs);
?>
```

The data I am sending through query is not getting stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem here. You are seeing

```
resource(3) of type (odbc result)
```

because that's the type of object that `$rs` actually is (and `var_dump` is telling you that). According to the PHP documentation, `odbc_exec`...

> Returns an ODBC result identifier if the SQL command was executed successfully, or FALSE on error.

(ref: [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php)). `$rs` is not `FALSE`, so the INSERT encountered no errors. (At least none that PHP knows about, anyway....)